# What is the best way to describe the turn order in Puerto Rico?

Tags: terminology

Inspired by [this question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/18726/is-the-snake-turn-order-for-blokus-fairer-than-the-traditional-turn-order) which describes the "snake turn", is there a good label to give the turn order in [Puerto Rico](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puerto_Rico_(board_game)), where the first player starts the round, then the second player starts the round, then the third player starts the round etc.

The reason I'm asking is so that I can more quickly get through that part of the explanation of the rules.  We always seem to spend a few minutes explaining that part.

Answer (score 4):

Just say the turns have a 'rotating starting player'.  If you have players familiar with poker or card games in general, you can use the dealer & blinds as an example.